# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid texture for sprite'

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Having abit of a problem with the above error.Im making a simple slider puzzle where ive added medium / hard levels. The easy level works no problems at all, but when i chose the medium or hard it throws this error out occasionally. 60% of the time they work fine but then the app crashes the other times.

What i dont understand is that it works fine for the easy levels but adding a medium level it gets problems. Heres the code if anyone wants to have a look.

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",imgValue];
CCTexture2D * texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:name];
NSMutableArray *imgFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
        CCSpriteFrame *imgFrame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:CGRectMake(i*56, j*56, 56, 56) offset:CGPointZero];
        [imgFrames addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imgFrame, @"frame", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self hashOfXY:i y:size.height-1-j]], @"check", nil]];
```

Thats the only error it throws out in the title. If anyone could help id be greatful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your texture cache is cleared at some point. Check applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning if code there clears the cache unintentionally.